# Entity referencedOn using foreign key instead of Entity ID

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-exposed

So I'm using Kotlin Exposed DAO API. let's say I have in my structure an id that I use internally and another that I would export to obfuscate which record is which, still having the from:to relationship in my database.

So I have my entities:

```
UserEntity(id: EntityID<Int>) : IntEntity(id) {
    companion object : IntEntityClass<UserEntity>(TransactionTable)

    var externalId by UserTable.external_id
    var name by UserTable.name
    

TransactionEntity(id: EntityID<Int>) : IntEntity(id) {
    companion object : IntEntityClass<TransactionEntity>(TransactionTable)

    var userId by TransactionTable.user_id
    var value by TransactionTable.value

    //relationships
    var user by UserEntity referencedOn TransactionTable.user_id
```

and my transaction table

```
object TransactionTable: IntIdTable("transaction_1"){
    var user_id = integer("user_id").references(UserTable.external_id)
    var value= double("value")
```

The problem here is that even when my FK is referencing `external_id`, the entity will look for the IDs of the UserEntity, so I'll have an `IllegalStateException` telling me that there is no such User with id = "my_extenal_id"...

Can I reference my Entity's relationship to join using the FK, or even explicitly say which field I want it to use for the join, without using the DSL API?

I know I can fix that with DSL API, but I would like to keep using my DAO API...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Exposed DAO all references work with id column, so it's impossible to get it to work except if you'll define external_id as an id column like:

```kotlin
    object UserTable : IdTable<Int>("Users") {
        val pkColumn = integer("id").autoIncrement()
        val external_id = integer("external_id")
        override val id: Column<EntityID<Int>> = external_id.entityId()
    }
```

Comment: Hum, but then I would need my table to use only the external id as id, right.. that's a no go for me... But I feared that. thank you

Comment: Maybe the DAO API could have this feature in the future, like it is in Python's SqlAlchemy. you define the key to the relationship reference, or it seeks the reference of that particular field... It's very good to have the DAO, but it's kinda rigid in some cases